# how to delete spaces before string begin and after string ended

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have configuration file with Thousands of parameters
sometimes we by mistake set the value with some extra spaces as the following example

```
   # PARAM1="  /mnt/Config/EME/EM/Telecom TTI/VM rde.pcf "
```

so because that we get some errors , for example

```
  # cp $PARAM1 /tmp
    cp: cannot stat `/mnt/Config/EME/EM/Telecom': No such file or directory
    cp: cannot stat `TTI/VM': No such file or directory
    cp: cannot stat `rde.pcf': No such file or directory
```

please advice how to delete the spaces before value start and after value ended ,

in order to resolved kind of those errors

for example

before

```
    PARAMETER="  /mnt/Config/EME/EM/Telecom TTI/VM rde.pcf "
```

solution could be as the following example

```
  NEW_PARAMETER_WITHOUT_EXTRA_SPACE=` echo $PARAMETER | sed ....   `
```

the expected results:

```
  NEW_PARAMETER_WITHOUT_EXTRA_SPACE="/mnt/Config/EME/EM/Telecom TTI/VM rde.pcf"
```

.
.
.
.

- Remark – spaces could be between the file strings and that OK

  For example

  FILE=”/etc/Conf      OF HOSTS/results.txt”

What we want is only to delete the spaces before file start and after file ended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below sed command would remove all the spaces at the begining or  at the end of the line,

```
sed 's/^\s*\(.*\)\s*/\1/g' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo '      # PARAM1="  /mnt/Config/EME/EM/Telecom TTI/VM rde.pcf "       ' | sed 's/^\s*\(.*\)\s*/\1/g'
# PARAM1="  /mnt/Config/EME/EM/Telecom TTI/VM rde.pcf "
```

Comment: I see still spaces on your answer

Comment: @maihabunash It's not necessary to do forks if you're using bash. (see `bash --version`). If you aren't, consider not tagging the thread with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
PARAM1="  /mnt/Config/EME/EM/Telecom TTI/VM rde.pcf "
read -r NEW_PARAMETER_WITHOUT_EXTRA_SPACE <<< "$PARAM1"   ## Do IFS=$' \t' read ... if IFS was altered.
echo "$NEW_PARAMETER_WITHOUT_EXTRA_SPACE"
```

Output:

```
/mnt/Config/EME/EM/Telecom TTI/VM rde.pcf
```

Another:

```
shopt -s extglob
__=${PARAM1##+([[:blank:]])}
NEW_PARAMETER_WITHOUT_EXTRA_SPACE=${__%%+([[:blank:]])}
```

Yet another:

```
[[ $PARAM1 =~ ^[[:blank:]]*(.*)[[:blank:]]*$ ]]
NEW_PARAMETER_WITHOUT_EXTRA_SPACE=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```